# How to restrict an attribute of an element in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this XML code:

```
 <student>
    <name sex="male">
        <fname></fname>
        <lname></lname>
    </name>
</student>
```

What I want to do is to add a restriction to the `sex` attribute. `sex` attribute should only take *male* and *female* as their value.
I have basic knowledge of making this XML Schema. So far what I've done is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="name" type="nameType"/>
    <xs:element name="fname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="lname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="student" type="studentType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="nameType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="fname"></xs:element>
            <xs:element ref="lname"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="sex"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="studentType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="name"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add restriction to the value of the attribute as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="name" type="nameType"/>
    <xs:element name="fname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="lname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="student" type="studentType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="nameType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="fname"></xs:element>
            <xs:element ref="lname"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="sex">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="ar"></xs:enumeration>
                    <xs:enumeration value="en"></xs:enumeration>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="studentType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="name"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `xs:restriction` to limit an attribute to a fixed set of enumerations via `xs:enumeration`:

```
<xs:attribute name="sex">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="male"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="female"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

Two other observations:

1. You can shorten empty elements via `<el/>` notation.
2. In addition to allowing a `student` root element, your XSD would
   allow `name`, `fname`, and `lname` root elements.  This doesn't look
   right.  Perhaps you should define all or some of those locally
   rather than globally.

Here is your XSD with all of the above adjustments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="student" type="studentType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="studentType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="nameType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="nameType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="fname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="sex">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="male"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="female"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.